# Bad environment delimiter in a seemingly simple case

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, amsmath, mathtools

I keep getting 'bad environment delimiter, extra $ inserted' here, but I cannot pinpoint the error.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}

\[\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-{(v/c)^2}-\sum_{3}^{n}(\frac{v}{c})^{n!/(n-2)}/n}}\]

\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Having `\[` and `\]` inside `\begin{equation}` ... `\end{equation}` is a syntax error. Omit either `\[` and `\]` (in case you want a numbered displayed equation) or `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` (in case you want an unnumbered displayed equation).

Comment: `mathtools` is a package more robust of `amsmath` and contains it.

Comment: Incidentally, its not exactly clear in your formula what the summation in the denominator is taken over.

Comment: Summation is over powers of v/c, n goes into the denominator of the whole sum. I have no idea how to make it clearer, since my efforts to use \frac{\sum_...}{n} failed.